# Linux - thread-

Tags: linux, multithreading

usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccFeNCVC.o: in function `writer': uu.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to` sem_wait'
/usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `sem_post' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccFeNCVC.o: in function` reader':
uu.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `sem_wait' /usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to` sem_post'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccFeNCVC.o: in function `main': uu.c:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to` sem_init'
/usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `pthread_create' /usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to` pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `pthread_join' /usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0x2b6): undefined reference to` pthread_join'
/usr/bin/ld: uu.c:(.text+0x2de): undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ritweek@ritweek:~$

Answer (score 1):

Add `-pthread` parameter to your linker or `gcc` command

Comment: how to add -pthread parameter to gcc command?

Comment: If you are building your project from the command line using gcc just add this parameter to command. You can describe how you build your project.